# selector base on text() value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
```

I want to hide / delete the second `<p>` without using `.eq()`, or CSS `nth-child(2)`, I just want to catch the value if it's 2 then delete it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.filter()` function:

```
$('p').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == "2";
}).remove();
```

Comment: if I have 10 item and want to remove says few item, will it be efficient using filter?

Comment: how to do multiple condition? `return $(this).text() == "2" || $(this).text() =="3"` is this correct?